# connection timeout of 10 seconds expired, stopping - Break Connection forever

Tags: akka, spray, spray-client

I am trying to send a GET request to URL .

```
val pipeline: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = (
            sendReceive
         )

val result = Await.result(pipeline(Get(url)), DEFAULT_TIMEOUT)
```

Once I get the following response, after which our client doesn't send any following requests.

```
 [WARN] -  s.can.client.HttpClientConnection - Configured connecting timeout of 10 seconds expired, stopping
```

I have to restart the server to start sending the requests again.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug.

From Johannes Rudolph -

The problem might be is that the slot goes from Unconnected state to Unconnected which is not supported right now.

Unfortunately, the broken slot will persist until the host connector itself is shutdown.

The issue has been filed by Johannes -https://github.com/spray/spray/issues/1085